# Firebase data changes state but does not render component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I am trying to attatch a listener to the chatRoomIds subcollection for a specific user from the User collection.After retriving the chatroomIds for the specific users I have to loop through each to get the specific chatRoom document from the chatRoomIds array in which each element is an object containing chatRoomId that will be used to query for the specific chatRoom.The problem is that the state is working correctly but does not render the Messaage Card component unless I toggle another state in the Message component in the react dev tools on the messages link again after everything loads.

[image: User collection with chatRoomIds subcollection]

[image: ChatRooms collection]
[image: Messages component after loading]

[image: messageCard component renders after another state change happens manually or clicking the message link again after loading]

```
function Message() {

const [currentUser] = useAuthState(auth)

const [{user}] = useStateValue()
const {show, setNotificationPopup, setShow} = useChat();
const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [chatRoomArraySnap, error] = useCollection(db.collection("Users").doc(user?.uid).collection('ChatRoomIds'))
const chatList = []

const {setLoader, loader} = useLoader();
let chatRoomIds = []
let params = useParams();
const messageId = params.id;
const userObj = {
    email: user?.email,
    objId: user?.uid,

    userName: user?.displayName
};


useEffect(() => {
    {
        params.id ? setShow(true)
            :
            setShow(false)
    }

}, [])

useEffect(() =>{
    // chatList = []
    if(user.uid){
        db.collection("Users").doc(user.uid).collection('ChatRoomIds').get()
            .then(
            snapshot => {

                snapshot.docs.map((each) => {

                    // chatRoomIds.push(each.data())
                    db.collection('ChatRooms').where("chatRoomId", "==", each.data().id).orderBy('dateLastUpdated','desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                            chats.push(doc.data())
                            console.log(doc.data())
                        })

                        // setChats(chatList)
                        setLoading(false)





                        // snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                        //                            if (change.type === "added") {
                        //                                console.log("New : ", change.doc.data());
                        //                                chatList.push(change.doc.data())
                        //
                        //                            }
                        //                            if (change.type === "modified") {
                        //                                console.log("Modified : ", change.doc.data());
                        //                                setNotificationPopup(change.doc.data())
                        //
                        //                            }
                        //                            if (change.type === "removed") {
                        //                                console.log("Removed : ", change.doc.data());
                        //                            }
                        //                        })


                    })

                })
                console.log(chatRoomIds)
                // chatRoomIds?.map((each) => {
                //     db.collection('ChatRooms').where("chatRoomId", "==", each.id).orderBy('dateLastUpdated','desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                //         snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                //             chatList.push(doc.data())
                //             console.log(doc.data())
                //         })
                //
                //         setChats(chatList)
                //         setLoading(false)
                //
                //
                //
                //
                //
                //         // snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                //         //                            if (change.type === "added") {
                //         //                                console.log("New : ", change.doc.data());
                //         //                                chatList.push(change.doc.data())
                //         //
                //         //                            }
                //         //                            if (change.type === "modified") {
                //         //                                console.log("Modified : ", change.doc.data());
                //         //                                setNotificationPopup(change.doc.data())
                //         //
                //         //                            }
                //         //                            if (change.type === "removed") {
                //         //                                console.log("Removed : ", change.doc.data());
                //         //                            }
                //         //                        })
                //
                //
                //     })
                // })
            }

        )


        console.log(chatList)
        // if (chatRoomArraySnap) {
        //
        //     chatRoomArraySnap.docs.map((each) => {
        //         chatRoomIds.push(each.data())
        //     })
        //     // chatList=[]
        //     // setChats([])
        //
        //     chatRoomIds.map((each) => {
        //         db.collection('ChatRooms').where("chatRoomId", "==", each.id).orderBy('dateLastUpdated','desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        //             snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        //                 chatList.push(doc.data())
        //             })
        //
        //
        //
        //
        //
        //
        //             // snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        //             //                            if (change.type === "added") {
        //             //                                console.log("New : ", change.doc.data());
        //             //                                chatList.push(change.doc.data())
        //             //
        //             //                            }
        //             //                            if (change.type === "modified") {
        //             //                                console.log("Modified : ", change.doc.data());
        //             //                                setNotificationPopup(change.doc.data())
        //             //
        //             //                            }
        //             //                            if (change.type === "removed") {
        //             //                                console.log("Removed : ", change.doc.data());
        //             //                            }
        //             //                        })
        //
        //
        //         })
        //     })
        //     setChats(chatList)
        //     console.log(chatList)
        //
        // }
    }

},[])

return (
    <>


        <Header/>
        <div className='container'>


            <div className='message '>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 lg-view'>
                        <div className=' pt-3 user-list-section'>
                            <div className='lg-view'>
                                <h5 className='text-light ml-5 mb-5`'>Messages</h5>
                                <div className={`d-flex align-items-center`}>
                                    <Search  functionHandler={handleSearchChat} props={'#13161A'}/>
                                    <CreateGroupBtn/>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div className='user-list'>
                                {!loading && chats ? chats.map(chat => {
                                    // console.log(chat.data());
                                    return (<>

                                            <MessageCard  key={chat.chatRoomId}
                                                          id={chat.chatRoomId} chats={chat}/>


                                        </>
                                    )
                                }) : <></>}

                            </div>


                        </div>


                    </div>
                    {
                        !show ? <>
                                <div className='sm-view   w-100 pl-3 pr-3 '>
                                    <div className=' w-100  d-flex justify-content-center  pt-4'>
                                        <div className='flex-grow-1'>
                                            <h4 className='text-light'>Messages</h4>
                                            <p>Talk with your friends</p>


                                        </div>

                                        <div className="search-container flex-grow-1 ">
                                            <div className='search  d-flex float-right'>
                                                <CreateGroupBtn/>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <Search functionHandler={handleSearchChat}/>


                                </div>

                                <div className='col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 sm-view'>
                                    <div className=' pt-3 user-list-section'>
                                        <div className='lg-view'>
                                            <h5 className='text-light ml-5 mb-5`'>Messages</h5>
                                            <div className={`d-flex align-items-center`}>
                                                <Search functionHandler={handleSearchChat} props={'#13161A'}/>
                                                <CreateGroupBtn/>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>
                                        <div className='user-list'>
                                            {!loading && chats !== undefined && chats !== null && chats ? chats.map(chat => {
                                                // console.log(chat.data());
                                                return (<>

                                                        <MessageCard  key={chat.chatRoomId}
                                                                     id={chat.chatRoomId} chats={chat}/>


                                                    </>
                                                )
                                            }) : <></>}
                                        </div>


                                    </div>


                                </div>

                            </>
                            :
                            <>
                                <div className='col-md-8 p-0 col-lg-8 col-sm-12'>
                                    {
                                        messageId && currentUser.email && <MessageWindow/>

                                    }

                                </div>

                            </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!show && <MobileNavbar/>}
    </>

);
}
```

[image: Updated photo]

///Working Code

```
function Message() {

const [currentUser] = useAuthState(auth)

const [{user}] = useStateValue()
const {show, setShow} = useChat();
const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

let params = useParams();
const messageId = params.id;



useEffect(() => {
    {
        params.id ? setShow(true)
            :
            setShow(false)
    }

}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if (user.uid) {
        db.collection("Users")
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection("ChatRoomIds")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.map((each) => {
                    db.collection("ChatRooms")
                        .where("chatRoomId", "==", each.data().id)
                        .orderBy("dateLastUpdated", "desc")
                        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                            console.log(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
                            setChats((chats) =>
                                chats.concat(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
                            );
                            setLoading(false)
                        });
                });
            });
    }
}, []);

return (
    <>


        <Header/>
        <div className='container'>


            <div className='message '>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 lg-view'>
                        <div className=' pt-3 user-list-section'>
                            <div className='lg-view'>
                                <h5 className='text-light ml-5 mb-5`'>Messages</h5>
                                <div className={`d-flex align-items-center`}>
                                    <Search functionHandler={handleSearchChat} props={'#13161A'}/>
                                    <CreateGroupBtn/>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div className='user-list'>
                                {/*{!loading && chats ? chats.map(chat => {*/}
                                {/*    // console.log(chat.data());*/}
                                {/*    return (<>*/}

                                {/*            <MessageCard key={chat.chatRoomId}*/}
                                {/*                         id={chat.chatRoomId} chats={chat}/>*/}


                                {/*        </>*/}
                                {/*    )*/}
                                {/*}) : <></>}*/}

                            </div>


                        </div>


                    </div>
                    {
                        !show ? <>
                                <div className='sm-view   w-100 pl-3 pr-3 '>
                                    <div className=' w-100  d-flex justify-content-center  pt-4'>
                                        <div className='flex-grow-1'>
                                            <h4 className='text-light'>Messages</h4>
                                            <p>Talk with your friends</p>


                                        </div>

                                        <div className="search-container flex-grow-1 ">
                                            <div className='search  d-flex float-right'>
                                                <CreateGroupBtn/>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <Search functionHandler={handleSearchChat}/>


                                </div>

                                <div className='col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 sm-view'>
                                    <div className=' pt-3 user-list-section'>
                                        <div className='lg-view'>
                                            <h5 className='text-light ml-5 mb-5`'>Messages</h5>
                                            <div className={`d-flex align-items-center`}>
                                                <Search functionHandler={handleSearchChat} props={'#13161A'}/>
                                                <CreateGroupBtn/>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>
                                        <div className='user-list'>
                                            {!loading && chats ? chats.map(chat => {

                                                return (<>

                                                        <MessageCard key={chat.chatRoomId}
                                                                     id={chat.chatRoomId} chats={chat}/>


                                                    </>
                                                )
                                            }) : <></>}
                                        </div>


                                    </div>


                                </div>

                            </>
                            :
                            <>
                                <div className='col-md-8 p-0 col-lg-8 col-sm-12'>
                                    {
                                        messageId && currentUser.email && <MessageWindow/>

                                    }

                                </div>

                            </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!show && <MobileNavbar/>}
    </>

);
}

export default Message;
```

Answer (score 2):

You've a lot of commented out code, but what isn't commented out has a glaring issue, state mutation. You are pushing directly into the `chats` state array. This is why you have to toggle/update some other state in order to trigger the component to rerender and expose the mutation.

You should properly enqueue these `chat` updates. On the last/innermost snapshot you should use a functional state update to update from the previous state and because you are working in a loop, and concatenate an array of new chat documents.

[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
> does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  setChats((chats) =>
    chats.concat(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
  );
});
```

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user.uid) {
    db.collection("Users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("ChatRoomIds")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.map((each) => {
          db.collection("ChatRooms")
            .where("chatRoomId", "==", each.data().id)
            .orderBy("dateLastUpdated", "desc")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
              setChats((chats) =>
                chats.concat(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
              );
            });
        });
      });
  }
}, []);
```

#### Update - to resolve duplicates

Still use a functional state update but run the `chats` array through a filter first to check if there are no new chats with matching `chatRoomId` properties. If there is a match return false to remove it from the array, otherwise keep it. The filter function returns a new array that you can concatenate to the new chats results.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user.uid) {
    db.collection("Users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("ChatRoomIds")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.map((each) => {
          db.collection("ChatRooms")
            .where("chatRoomId", "==", each.data().id)
            .orderBy("dateLastUpdated", "desc")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
              const newChats = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
              setChats((chats) => {
                const filtered = chats.filter(chat => 
                  !newChats.some(newChat => 
                    newChat.chatRoomId === chat.chatRoomId
                  )
                );
                newChats.concat(filtered);
              });
            });
        });
      });
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Works well!!!!!Thanks. Although when changes are made it returns the changed document and adds it to the state how can I eliminate that. See the updated photo

Comment: @johnoula Sorry, it's unclear to me what you are asking about. Are you basically saying the changed/updated documents are being added as duplicates, and are you asking how to prevent this? Is this related to the code in my answer or is this something in the commented out code?

Comment: related to your code.See the updated photo.Yes as duplicates and yes.In the photo 'Group' was updated and caused a duplicate which i think is expected with your code

Comment: @johnoula I see. Is there a field/property in the `chats` array elements to match/filter by/compare to the `doc.data()`?

Comment: @johnoula Sorry, I should have more explicit, I meant any `id` or GUID's that uniquely identify an entry so duplicates can be thrown out. You basically want to replace the previous copy, or append if new. Is this correct understanding?

Comment: It is working. But the new chat is being appended at the end instead of being appended at the beginning. Also, if there is a new chat it rerenders the MessageCard component only the first time there is a new chat(after it has been appended at the end) ,If a new chat comes in after the first one everything works well by it only updating the new chat